# ¿Por qué se cambia la hora al insertar en Mysql?

Tags: java, mysql

Tengo un código en Spring con java 8 para insertar la fecha y hora actual en mi base de datos Mysql 5.7, el problema es que cuando reviso la base de datos le agrega una hora más a la que corresponde, el tipo de dato en la base de datos es Datetime.

Ya comprobé el time_zone en Mysql con **`SELECT @@time_zone`** y me muestra:

```
+-------------+
| @@time_zone |
+-------------+
| SYSTEM      |
+-------------+
```

y también **`select now();`** y me muestra la hora actual correctamente.

Mi código es el siguiente:

En mi clase donde lo implemento:

```
LocalDateTime actual = LocalDateTime.now();
DTO.getPer().setDateUpdate(actual);
```

En el modelo:

```
@Column(name = "date_update")
private LocalDateTime dateUpdate;
```

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Deberias ver que timezone esta usando JAVA con TimeZone.getDefault().getID() y ajustar JAVA timezone con TimeZone.getDefault().setID("YOUR TIME ZONE");

Comment: tienes la base de datos MySQL local o en el cloud?

Comment: @BetaM Gracias por la respuesta, si he estado viendo eso y haciendo algunas prueba pero al parecer estoy trabajando correctamente con mi zona horaria.

Comment: @toto Gracias por la respuesta, he aplicado lo que comentas y si es correcta mi zona horaria.

Comment: @JPRLCol en local.

Comment: Si imprimis en consola la variable actual que hora muestra. ?

Comment: @toto muestra la hora correcta, en java también muestra la hora correcta, la zona horaria de mi sistema operativo (os x catalina) también es correcta, gracias.